# template doesn't work when I add my packages

Tags: packages, templates

I'm using my school template (you can find it here: https://www.overleaf.com/project/62f50d65cfee1198bb5f2e7e). This works perfectly, I can fill in everything and paste my text into it and it looks fine.

However when I add the packages I'm using, nothing shows anymore (no pictures on the main page, no layout, nothing)

I add the packages like this into the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

% Load the VUB package.
% This has many options, please read the documentation at
% https://gitlab.com/rubdos/texlive-vub
\usepackage{bruface}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./img/} }
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[
  separate-uncertainty = true,
  multi-part-units = repeat
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

% Some highly suggested packages, please read their manuals.
%\usepackage{cleveref}
%\usepackage[natbib,style=apa]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\title{mytitle}
\pretitle{\flushleft{Graduation thesis submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of engineering sciences: Applied Sciences and Engineering: Applied Computer Science }}
\author{name}
\date{2021-2022}
\supervisor{Prof.blabla}
\programme{Applied Sciences and Engineering: Applied Computer Science}

% Pick one:
% \programme{Architectural Engineering}
%\programme{Chemical and Materials Engineering}
%\programme{Civil Engineering}
%\programme{Electrical Engineering}
%\programme{Electromechanical Engineering}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle%

\chapter{Abstract}
etc....
Your abstract would go here.

\tableofcontents%

\mainmatter%
\part{First part}%

Optionally, you use parts, and those parts contain chapters.

\part{Second Part}%

Optionally, you use parts, and those parts contain chapters.

\backmatter%
\chapter{Conclusion}

%\printbibliography%
\end{document}
```

The errors are:

- LaTeX Error: Command @pretitle already defined. (I checked, it's only defined once)
- LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} but I have defined it, and again, this works fine without using my addition of the following:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./img/} }
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[
  separate-uncertainty = true,
  multi-part-units = repeat
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Two \documentclass statements?  In any case, the documentation should list incompativle packages.

Comment: You did not show the error message, but it is very clear: `! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.`

Answer (score 0):

Both users @David Carlisle and @John Kormylo were correct. I have removed the duplicate \documentclass statements as well as the incompatible package `titling` and everything works fine now.